# Get Document in Couchbase v2.0

Tags: java, android, database, couchbase-lite

I used to use **com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.0.0-DB008** until last week, and know it seems to be removed, because I couldn't import it to the Gradle in android studio, so I had to use the latest version of couchbase **com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:2.0.0-158**.

With this version I can't retrieve the Documents, because it doesn't have **getDocumentId()** method and we can't use **database.getDocument(docID)**;

This is the code of document I have saved:

```
        Document document = new Document();
        document.setInt("RecordType", 100);
        document.setString("Number", "1234567890");
        document.setDate("Date", new Date());
        document.setString("Text", "This is message text.");

        try {
            database.save(document);
            tvResult.setText(document.getId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            tvResult.setText(e.toString());
        }
```

and this is the code that should retrieve the document:

```
Query query = Query.select()
            .from(DataSource.database(database))
            .where(
                    Expression.property("RecordType").equalTo(100)
            );

    try {
        ResultSet rows = query.run();
        Result row;
        while ((row = rows.next()) != null) {

            row.hashCode()

            tvResult.append("DocumentID: " + row.getString("documentID") + "\n" +
                    "Number: " + row.getString("Number") + "\n" +
                    "Date: " + row.getDate("Date") + "\n\n"
            );

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        tvResult.setText(e.toString());
    }
```

All of the rows gives null data.

Is there any way that we can retrieve all the documents and their ID?

Answer (score -1):

First, I'd upgrade if I were you.  DB-018 is out, and each version is fixing significant bugs.  But be careful-  DB-013 changed the sync protocol, so you'll need to upgrade your server as well.

Second, as of either DB017 or DB018, you MUST specify the fields you wish to get, or search results are empty rows like you see.  I'm not sure if this is intended or a bug.  Specifying "" will give you all fields.  Note that it will NOT give you a Document, it will give you a Dictionary.

Truthfully I find the easiest way to get the id is to embed it in the document itself.  There's probably some meta field you can request, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: There is a `Meta` class that you can use for getting information like the ID.  `Expression.meta().id` or equivalent is what you can put into the Select.